# Ember.js clear controller on transitionToRoute call

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that displays a list of parcels, and an Ember.Select that allows the user to select which state's parcels to show.

#### Model

```
App.Parcel = DS.Model.extend({
    addresses: DS.attr('array')
});
```

#### Route

```
App.ParcelsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  state: null,
  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render({ outlet: 'parcels' });
  },
  model: function (params) {
    state = params.state;
    App.ParcelAdapter.state = state;
    App.ImageAdapter.state = state;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        props: this.store.findAll('parcel'),
        states: this.store.findAll('state'),
    });
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('states', model.states);
    controller.set('props', model.props);
    controller.set('selectedState', state);
  }
});
```

#### Controller

```
App.ParcelsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedState: null,
  props: null,
  states: null,
  first: true,
  modelReloadNeeded: function () {
    if (this.get('selectedState') != undefined && !this.get('first')) {
        this.transitionToRoute('/parcels/' + this.get('selectedState'));
    }else{
        this.set('first', false);
    }
  }.observes('selectedState')
});
```

#### Handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="parcels">
    {{view Ember.Select content=states optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.id" value=selectedState}}
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search"/>
    <ul class="list nav">
        {{#each props}}
        <li>{{#link-to 'parcel' this}}<h3 class="name">{{addresses.0.street_address}}</h3>{{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

When the select transitions to the new route, both the old routes data and new routes are in the model, but if I reload the page, only the current routes data is loaded. Is there a way to clear the DS.RecordArray for props in the controller without a location.reload() call?

Comment: Are you sure you want a copy of the states/props in the controller?  Like are you using those as dirty attributes or something?

Comment: They can be nested as the model. I have the same issue if the controller used the default controller.set('model', model). The goal is to have the modelReloadNeeded method change the namespace on the RESTAdapter and refresh the list with the new results. The request logs are show it is not requesting the old states data, but appends the new data to it. Reloading the page clears that old data.